# Program doesn't write on the standard output and gets stuck instead

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, argv

I'm writing this software that should open a file, that must be passed as an argument,  and write the content of the file on the standard output using the open and write system calls. (It's a bit like the `cat` command)

The problem is that once I run the program as

```
./a.out /example/pattern/file
```

it writes on the standard output the pattern of the file and then it gets stuck, without writing anything or terminating, allowing me even to write on the terminal.

I've tried using the ddd debugger, but I wasn't able to find the problem.

All the necessary headers are included.

```
int main(int argc,char * argv[]){

    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    int fd, lung;
    char buf[10];
    if(fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)==-1){
        perror("argv[1], in apertura");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(lung = read(fd,buf,10)>0){
        if( (write(1, buf, lung))==-1) perror("error");
    }
    if (lung==-1) {perror("error");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
    fflush(NULL);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop in the `while` loop?

Comment: wont't read return 0 when it'll reaches the end of file, terminating the loop?

Comment: Operator precedence: `while(lung = read(fd,buf,10)>0)` -> `while((lung = read(fd,buf,10))>0)`

Comment: Please check `argc` before using `argv` - it's so easy to forget to provide the necessary arguments. It should be *de rigueur* like many other checks.

Comment: @GerardoZinno please don't correct errors commenters reveal, in the question. It makes the whole dialog look pointless.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you.

Comment: @WeatherVane the problem was in the while and the error is still there, I edited the post because I didn't see the edit to the answer of gsamaras and when I tried what he said the error was still there.

Comment: Again:((  Why do devs continually write compound expressions?  They so often get them wrong:(   Please, please stop with the 'clever' code!

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: You mentioned in the question that all the headers are there, however; they are completely missing in the posted code.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which headers you included in the code?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: when the code performs a 'sudden' exit, do not let the OS fix things,  rather have the code cleanup after itself.  In this case, once the file is open, if suddenly exiting the program, be sure to call `close()` to cleanup before calling `exit()`

Comment: with a modern C compiler, there is no need to call `return` unless returning something other than 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that suspicious?

```
if(fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)==-1) {
```

According to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `==` will be executed before `=`.

Then:

```
while(lung = read(fd,buf,10)>0){
```

will similarly suffer from `>` been executed before `=`.

Tip: When in doubt, use parentheses! ;)

Comment: I just tried adding parenthesis but the result hasn't changed

Comment: @GerardoZinno copy paste here your modified code. Did you see my edit?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit. That was the problem. Thanks

Comment: @GerardoZinno great. Also a good habit is to check for `argc`, but I know now that this wan't the problem, for sure. I remember when I had this error when I started programming, +1 by me.

Comment: I checked for argc, but I knew it was not the problem so I wrote here just the portion of code I knew had an error

Comment: Bello @GerardoZinno!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(lung = read(fd,buf,10)>0){
    if( (write(1, buf, lung))==-1) perror("error");
}
```

is the same as (due to operator precedence ):

```
while(lung = (read(fd,buf,10)>0) ){
    if( (write(1, buf, lung))==-1) perror("error");
}
```

The value of `lung` will be either `1` or `0`. When it is `0`, the loop will break When it is `1`, only `1` character will be written to `stdout`.

What you need is:

```
while( (lung = read(fd,buf,10)) > 0 ){
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.

Comment: little oops there:  this line: `while( (lung = (read(fd,buf,10)) > 0 ) ){`  should really be: `while( (lung = read(fd,buf,10)) > 0  ){`  so the assignment will be performed before the comparison as the comparison will then be the result of the assignment.

Comment: @user3629249, thanks for pointing out the error. it's fixed now.